# Accessing folders via MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to access some .m folders that I have downloaded into `Downloads`. How can I access this folder and run the files using `cd` similar to how I would on a Terminal (MacOS)? The same statements don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the absolute path of your `Downloads` folder, e.g.:

```
current_dir = pwd;
cd('C:\Users\you_username\Downloads')
```

Then, you'll be able to access the files in that folder. When you are finished, you can then return to your original folder with:

```
cd(current_dir);
```

An alternative is to add the `Downloads` folder to your MATLAB path with [`addpath`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html). You should then be able to access files in there from any directory of your choosing without having to `cd`. If you want to make that change to the MATLAB path permanent, use [`savepath`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savepath.html) afterwards to save the MATLAB path for future sessions.

Answer (score 2):

All of the regular commands for linux should work.

ls, dir, cd 'your folder goes here' , cd ,, , cd.. etc

Comment: I have been trying `cd Downloads` but it shows that the directory does not exist.

Comment: @S_SDhar you can use `pwd` to display your "working directory", where matlab considers itself currently, you may have to do more navigating than just `cd Documents`

Comment: Ok I used `pwd` and now I have a location-how do I navigate from there?

Comment: cd 'Downloads' only works IF you are in the folder with downloads otherwise it needs to be cd 'C:\....etc' with the '